# MEAN edit model popup show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i was trying to fetch data from mysql

```
app.controller('getdata', function ($http, $scope) {

$scope.editData = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.clickUser = data;
} 
});
```

this is console

```
Object {id: 2, name: " Mitukula Vishal", email: " venkateshmitukula@gmail.com", password: " 123456", city: " hyderabad"…}$$hashKey: "object:8"city: " hyderabad"email: " venkatesh123@gmail.com"id: 2name: " Mitukula "password: " 123456"__proto__: Object
```

View page edit popup

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  ng-click="editData(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</a>  <br>
```

model popup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-body">
  Name <input type="text"  ng-model="clickUser.name" class="form-control" /><br>
</div>
</div> <br>
```

All i was trying to get data here. But im unable to get in popup

Comment: Where in your HTML are you attaching your `getData` controller? Your `ng-model` directive won't work if it's not in scope.

Comment: ohh then how can i get values ! is their any alternative ways.

Comment: Attach the controller, so that your model is in scope. Try the following: `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="getData">`

Comment: thanks, but its not working and getting this error Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped your controller name with camel case. Try this: `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="getdata">`

Comment: error gone , but still not getting data in popup